# vb.net send mail smtp and outlook error (individually)

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, smtp

```
 'Variable which will send the mail
Dim obj As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

'Variable to store the attachments 
Dim Attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment

'Variable to create the message to send
Dim Mailmsg As New Mail.MailMessage()
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        Dim ol As New Outlook.Application()
        Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim fdMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ns.Logon(, , True, True)

        'creating a new MailItem object
        Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem

        'gets defaultfolder for my Outlook Outbox
        fdMail = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox)



        'assign values to the newMail MailItem
        newMail = fdMail.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
        newMail.Subject = "tesst"
        newMail.Body = "test"
        newMail.To = TextBox1.Text
        Dim sSource As String = Application.StartupPath + "\kk.sys"
        ' TODO: Replace with attachment name
        Dim sDisplayName As String = "kaar.jpg"

        Dim sBodyLen As String = newMail.Body.Length


        newMail.SaveSentMessageFolder = fdMail

        newMail.Send()

    Catch ex As Exception


        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\err1.txt")

            writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString)



        End Using

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim address As New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text, "Nigraan")
        Dim oAttch As Mail.Attachment = New Mail.Attachment(Application.StartupPath + "\kk.sys")
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
        SmtpServer.Port = "587"
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text)
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text))
        mail.Subject = TextBox3.Text
        mail.Body = "test"


        mail.Attachments.Add(oAttch)

        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\err2.txt")

            writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString)



        End Using
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & TextBox1.Text & "?subject=" & "re:Subject" & "&body=" & "EmailBody")
    Catch ex As Exception

        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\err3.txt")

            writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString)



        End Using
    End Try
End Sub`
```

errors are:

err1:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): There must be at least one name or distribution list in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Send()
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

err2:

System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: address
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

When i send using a machine with visual studio both mail gets sent, when not these errors show.

i have double checked .net framework

thank you..

Comment: the same results come with or without this code    'Dim address As New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text, "Nigraan")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got everything working,

got smtp to work by giving ssl encryption to true

got outlook to work by creating a contact and giving the contact's email id in the 'to' field

just don't save the contact if u don't want the contact to be added in outlook :D

yeyyy!!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable string and set that before sending the mail

```
Dim ToEmail as string
ToEmail = Textbox1.text
```

Then set your to address first.

```
'assign values to the newMail MailItem
    newMail.To = ToEmail
    newMail = fdMail.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    newMail.Subject = "tesst"
    newMail.Body = "test"
```

Comment: smtp is working by putting ssl to true.. outlook is still not working after putting it into a variable also, same issue...